# How can i use react-leaflet with https?

Tags: ssl, react-leaflet

Is it possible to use react-leaflet with https connection?

It seems I cannot switch between HTTP and HTTPS protocol, so i get a warning:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/map' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://b.tile.osm.org/10/510/340.png'. This content should also be
>   served over HTTPS.

Maybe somebody knows a workaround.

Comment: You just need to specify HTTPS in your tile URLs.

Comment: This article may help you https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/what-is-mixed-content-warnings

Comment: Thanks! indeed its just url in tile component. have no idea how i miss it..